# Showing data by percentage on Pie Charts in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

In my MVC5 application I have table lets's say it's name is Student and every student belonging to a Team. I want to show students according to their teams by percentage. For this reason I also created a ViewModel in order to join **Student** entity with **Team** entity. So, how can I show the data I want on Kendo UI pie chart? Could you have a look at the code and correct the mistakes below? And could you give a View samples suitable to this approach? Thanks in advance.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public int TeamPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dataContext = repository.Student;

    var result = dataContext.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new StudentViewModel
        {
            StudentId = m.StudentId,
            TeamId = m.TeamId,
            TeamName = m.TeamName,

            TeamPercentage = //??? How can I obtain percentage by Lambda Expression ???
        }
    );
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**Viewmodel**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller** (note I've made some assumptions in the query)

```
public ActionResult Index_Read()
{
    var teamCount = repository.Team.Count();
    var result = repository.Student.GroupBy(g => g.TeamName).Select(s => new StudentViewModel { category = s.Key, value = s.Count()/teamCount });
    // Imagine result contains something like this: { category = "Team 1", value = "20" }, { category = "Team 2", value = "30" }, { category = "Team 3", value = "10" }, { category = "Team 4", value = "40" }
    return View(result);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
    .Name("chart")
    .Title(title => title.Text("Teams").Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
    .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(true))
    .Series(series => series.Pie(Model))
)
```

**Alternative**

Another way to do it would be using a data source binding.

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string TeamName{ get; set; }
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
}

@(Html.Kendo().Chart<StudentViewModel>()
    .Name("chart2")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read("GetTeamData", "Home"))
    .Series(series => series.Pie(m => m.Percentage, model => model.TeamName))
)
```

Comment: Although I managed to set the appropriate properties with the related data (Name and Percentage) by grouping, there is nothing on the Chart. I think the chart definition on the View should be fixed. Could you have a look at above and correct it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've fixed the code and added an alternative way. Tested it and it's working fine here. Should be enough to get you on your way.

Comment: Everything is OK except from rendering the Chart on the View page. The only problem was related to "converting int to string". When I use TeamName string value on the ViewModel and try to us it on Controller as equal to "s.Key" I encounter an error. So, I use toString() method in order to fix the problem. But although there is no error and the data could be sent from the Controller correctly, the chart is not rendered and there is nothing on it except from a title. >>>

Comment: >>> I have all the necessary css and javascript file and I can see the pie chart when I use static context as on http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pie-charts/index. So, what is the problem regarding to the Index page or rendering method?

Comment: Obviously I don't know your database structure, my query is just an example. You really should have enough information to implement this now. Note that your model must have properties named "category" and "value", unless you use the second example with the lambda expression.

Comment: Finally I managed to show data by using "Google Charts" instead of Kendo Chart. I think there is no error on the ViewModel and Controller side. The only problem related to Kendo Chart is the code in the View. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. As you solved the getting data by percentage, I marked your reply as answer. On the other hand, if you provide a View containing Kendo Pier chart (and also dataSource property) it will be nice to try for me. Thanks a lot again...